# solutions of a linear equation system

Tags: linear-algebra

The following matrix is given over $\mathbb R$

A=$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & a \\ 1 & a & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

The linear equation System $Ax=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ has exactly one solution for all $a$ except $a=-2$ which has no solution. Is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost correct.

- At $a = -2$, we have no solution, so you are correct on that.
- At $a = 0$, our augmented RREF matrix gives:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

This means we have infinite solutions as:

$x = 1, y = -1 + z$, where $z$ is a free variable.

- At all other $a$, we have a single unique solution.

Comment: RREF, solutions or lack thereof for what values of $a$...? (Popular assigned problem-type presently!) +1 for the assistance!

Comment: @amWhy: There does seem to be an awful rash of those lately! Maybe instructors are running out of other problems and they can add variables all over the matrix! :-)

Comment: this is the reduced form:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 2(a+1)/(a+2)  \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1/(-a-2) \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1/(-a-2) \end{bmatrix}$$

a=-2 will be not defined (division by 0) and therefore i've to handle this case separately. But it seems for all other cases $Rank(A)=Rank(A´)=3$ (exactly one solution). But for a=0 there are of course infinite solutions. I am unable to see this regarding the reduced form !?

Comment: Sometimes, you need to look at several things and you always start with the determinant which is $-a(a+2)$. That shows the two points of interest $0$ and $-2$. Then, I do the general RREF and then handle the special cases as sometimes those are not always evident from the reduced form. Regards

Comment: my current basic math course will not give me the term "determinant" :/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant. You can also solve for each variable and will see those two pints if you cannot  use the determinant. Lastly, during the rref reduction, if you don't take it all the way, you can see those critical points. Regards

Comment: i've divided by $a$ that was the mistake

Comment: No, I would not say it was a mistake, you just need to keep track of it is all. Regards

Answer (score 1):

We see that $det(A)=-a(a+2)$. A matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if $det(A)\neq 0$. When $a=0$ there exist an infinite number of solutions. When $a=-2$ there exists no solution.

Comment: if a=0 then $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1\\1 & 0 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

the augmented matrix will be

$$B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1 & | & 2\\1 & 0 & 0 & | & 1\\1 & 0 & 0 & | & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

the row reduced form:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & | & 1\\0 & 1 & 1 & | & -1\\0 & 0 & 0 & | & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

$Rank(A)=Rank(B)=2 \ne n$ => exactly one solution ???

Comment: Amzoti cleared the issue.

Comment: We would have $x=1$ and $y+z=-1$ which implies an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: i am wrong: Rank(A)=Rank(B)=2≠n => infinite solutions

Comment: No worries. You had me looking through my Linear Algebra - Friedberg textbook to make sure that $a=0$ would imply an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: but now i am confused about the row reduced form:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & (2(a+1))/(a+2) \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1/(-a-2) \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1/(-a-2 \end{bmatrix}$$

ok, no problem that a=-2 is not defined and therefore to handle this case separately and for all other cases the Rank(A)=Rank(B)=3=n which means there is exactly one solution. but how to see that if $a=0$ there are infinite solutions regarding this ?

Comment: any hints to this ?